# multiple Runnables on single thread versus one runnable with for loop

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency

I have an executor that allows consumer to decide the size of the pool. But if a consumer picks 1, then I end up  with a number of Runnables running in one thread. So the question: is it better to have one runnable making a bunch of server calls in a loop? or is it better to have a runnable per call? My question is to help evaluate if I should present a special case for when user sets pool size to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is to help evaluate if I should present a special case for when user sets pool size to 1.

It is probably better to *not* do something special if there is a pool size of 1 to make your code more consistent.  In terms of efficiency, having a number of `Runnable`s may be less efficient but probably would be a drop in the bucket compared to the server call.  So you should vote for better code consistency instead of premature optimization.

Just to be sure, it is always recommended that you use the `ExecutorService` classes to build your thread pools.

```
// create a thread pool with some number of workers chosen by the user
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreadsInPool);
for (MyRunnable job : runnablesToDo) {
   threadPool.submit(job);
}
// once we have submitted all jobs to the thread pool, it should be shutdown
threadPool.shutdown();
```